# Question about independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

First of all is true that given $X,Y$ two random variables indenpendent; $(X,Y)\in D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$?

I tried to prove it and this is my solution:

If $D=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ is trivial.

But for a general $D$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent rv's and have finite variances then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ or equivalently $Cov(X,Y)=0$. This can be proved on a basical way. What do you mean by $(X,Y)\in D$? I suspect that $(X,Y)$ only takes values in $D$. It is not relevant here.

Comment: @drhab Probably it means the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$ has support $D$.

Comment: If $D$ serves as support of a pdf - as @M.Vinay suggests - then $\mathbb R^2$ also can serve as 'support'. Just expand the original pdf on $D$ and let it take the value $0$ for elements that are not in $D$. However, taking the whole space as 'support' takes away the need of using the term 'support'.

Comment: Exactly! You can ignore $D$ when doing any general computation with the pdf. It is needed only when you need to calculate values in a particular example. Recall that in all definitions (of the pdf, expected value, etc.), the limits are $\infty$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

In general: if $X$ and $Y$ are rv's with $\text{Var}X<\infty$ and
$\text{Var}Y<\infty$ then: $$\mathbb{E}XY=\int xydF_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then: $$F_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=F_{X}\left(x\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)$$
This leads to: $$\int xydF_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=\int\int xydF_{X}\left(x\right)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int xdF_{X}\left(x\right)\times\int ydF_{Y}\left(y\right)=\mathbb{E}X\times\mathbb{E}Y$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know what $D$ is. By definition of independence, $f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$. Then

$\begin{align}
E[XY] & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xy\, f(x, y)\, dx\,dy\\
 & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xy\, g(x)h(y)\, dx\,dy\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\, g(x)\, dx \times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y\, h(y)\, dy\\
& = E[X]E[Y]
\end{align}$

$\therefore \boxed{\text{Cov}[X, Y] = E[X, Y] - E[X]E[Y] = 0}$

Comment: Weak point: pdf's are used here. Off course it is also true if these do not exist. I hope it is enough for the OP, though.

Comment: @drhab You mean it doesn't cover the case of discrete variables?

Comment: For instance, yes. Also there are variables that are not discrete, but a pdf for their distribution lacks.

Comment: @drhab Ah, I see what you mean.